# Independent method for exporting classes to XML

Tags: java, xml

I have a class `Container`:

```
public class Container implements Exportable {
    private Node root;
    private String name;

    public void exportXML(Element target, Document document) {
        target.setAttribute("name", name);

        root.exportXML(target, document);
    }
}
```

Which implements the interface `Exportable` which defines two abstracts methods, one for importing, one for exporting. The objective is to export my classes to XML format.
As you can see, the class Container take a `Node` which is the root of a `Node` tree. This is the `Node` class:

```
public class Node implements Exportable {
    private ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;

    public void exportXML(Element target, Document document) {
        Element node = document.createElement("node");
        target.appendChild(node);
        node.setAttribute("name", name);

        if (children.size() > 0) {
            Element nodes = document.createElement("nodes");
            node.appendChild(nodes);

            for (Node child : children) {
                child.exportXML(nodes, document);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use a `SaveManager` class for exporting the `Container` object:

```
public class SaveManager {
    public static void exportContainer(Container container, String pathname) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
            Element projectNode = document.createElement("container");
            document.appendChild(projectNode);

            container.exportXML(projectNode, document);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(pathname));

            transformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to export the `Node` alone, without a `Container`. For example, if I call `nodeA.exportXML()`, the `nodeA` will be the root of the tree.

The problem is that I will have two methods in my `SaveManager` doing exactly the same thing (ie call exportXML() on an object and save the result into an XML file) and I will have to create to methods `exportXML()` in my `Node` class, one where the `Node` is a child and one where it's the root. I did exactly the same thing in C++ using `pugixml` and it was much easier because the document itself was a node, so I just had to give it to the exportXML() method if I wanted anything to be a root otherwise.

Is it possible to have a generic exportXML() method with the Java XML implementation?

Comment: Are you constained to use DOM (which does not scale for lot of data) and transformers and whatever? We have 2018 and there is a lot of more interesting and performant technologies (which do not pollute your data model with interfaces) .   Turning  your data to XML and back is usially 2-3 lines of code and so´me annotations with things like xstream

Comment: I would look at using JAXB, which does a lot of the grunt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking with the DOM approach, it looks like the simplest way to do this would be to let the `Container` create its own element.  Both `Node` and `Container` would then be able to add themselves to whatever parent `Document` or `Element` was passed in.

(We're about to have to deal with two `Node` classes here unfortunately, but ...) The trick to doing this is to use a `org.w3c.dom.Node` as the first parameter in `exportXML()` - this is the superinterface for both `Document` and `Element`, so can handle the root or child being passed in:

```
public class Container implements Exportable {
    private Node root;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public void exportXML(org.w3c.dom.Node target, Document document) {
        Element node = document.createElement("container");
        document.appendChild(node);
        node.setAttribute("name", name);

        root.exportXML(target, document);
    }
}
```

`SaveManager` can then just pass the `Document` in at the start:

```
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        //Element projectNode = document.createElement("container");
        //document.appendChild(projectNode);

        container.exportXML(document, document);
```

And your `Node` class should work unchanged, just with a `org.w3c.dom.Node target` passed in now.

But agree with the earlier comments about XStream or JAX-B.  For example most of the XML being generated so far would be well with the capabilities of a few `@XmlElement` and `@XmlAttribute` annotations.